# How UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(namespace) works?

Tags: apex, managed-package, licenses

I was trying setup conga dynamically using `Apex`. I need to find whether conga package is installed or not. So I wrote the following code:

```
Boolean isCongaInstalled = UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('APXTConga4__');
```

I am getting a type exception instead of `false` value as documented in salesforce for `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed` method. Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 6):

Try passing your namespace without double underscores to the method:

```
Boolean isCongaInstalled = UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('APXTConga4');
```